# Pokémon GO won't let me sign in with Google

Tags: pokemon-go

I keep trying to log in, but my keyboard won't come up. I tried restarting my phone and deleting and reinstalling the Pokémon GO app, but it doesn't help.

Comment: Does your keyboard work normally otherwise?

Answer (score 1):

The same happened to me. There's a button at the bottom of the app that is the Safari symbol. If you click that then it will redirect you to safari and you should be able to log in there. Once you log in it will ask you to go back to the app and you should be signed in. I hope this works for you!